# inexperienced in java. Fumbling my way through a REST API client

Tags: java, android

I'm cobbling a small android app together that I want to use for our team. All it is doing is calling to a REST API endpoint and hitting a bunch of queries. Status, alerts, some monitoring information.  Pretty simple. But I have spent 3 days staring at every site on Google that explains how to make a REST API call in Java, get back the JSON, and then store it as something like a hash where I can then just reference the JSON elements by name. I wrote a desktop version in Python and I'm thinking something like where Python just parses it into a DICT. So far I have some code. I'm not even sure if it works because I'm stuck with what to do next:

```
protected void getJSON() {
    String url = "http://192.168.8.29/api/v1/version";

    try {

        URL hmAPIEndPoint = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) hmAPIEndPoint.openConnection();

        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            // Success
            // Further processing here
            Log.d("getJSON", "Got a 200 back from the openConnection()");

            InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader responseBodyReader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");

            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(responseBodyReader);

            // I need jsonReader to be something I can reference like jsonReader['version_id']

            jsonReader.close();
            myConnection.disconnect();
        } else {
            Log.e("getJSON", "Didn't register a 200 response. Actual: " + myConnection.getResponseCode());
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException mfe) {
        Log.e("getJSON", mfe.getStackTrace().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getJSON", e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}
```

From here there are like 500 sites that tell me to just parse the json line by line but that seems... stupid.  Is there a way that I can get the jsonReader thing into an object like a described above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: change your question title. it will give you negative votes. you describe the details in your question but not in title

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You can go with [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) network library.

It will convert all your json to POJO.

Sample tutorial

https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23

### Option 2

Try to convert inputstream to POJO with help of GSON library

**Gson dependency**

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

**Sample tutorial**

http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html

Comment: So when I follow the Option 1 tutorial, Android Studio throws a bunch of errors about the "compile xxx" in the build.gradle.  It doesn't work.  Something about refactoring to Android X.